# JAXB in local Domino Agent on 9.0.1FP2

Tags: java, jaxb, lotus-domino

I have agent that uses JAXB to locally generate SEPA payment file. It works quite fine in 9.0.1, but not in 9.0.1FP2. Something had to change in jaxb  security. I couldn't test FP1, so I don't know which FP broke it.

On clean 9.0.1 it just complained, but worked

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection <init>
WARNING: Unable to make  iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.pain_001_001.Document.cstmrCdtTrfInitn accessible.
Throwable occurred: java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks)
at java.security.AccessController.throwACE(AccessController.java:100)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:174)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:544)
at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.AppletSecurity.superDotCheckPermission(AppletSecurity.java:1449)
at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.AppletSecurity.checkPermission(AppletSecurity.java:1617)
at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.AppletSecurity.checkPermission(AppletSecurity.java:1464)
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:118)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.<init>(Accessor.java:243)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.AccessorFactoryImpl.createFieldAccessor(AccessorFactoryImpl.java:67)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.createFieldSeed(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:253)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.createFieldSeed(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:82)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.findFieldProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:399)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:302)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getProperties(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:177)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:224)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:101)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:82)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:190)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:96)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:82)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:305)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:320)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:444)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:291)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1128)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:181)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:134)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:213)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:387)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:585)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:533)
at com.pradny.company.sepa.SepaExporter.generate(Unknown Source)
at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

But with FP2 Exception is propagated and kills the processing

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection <init>
WARNING: Unable to make iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.pain_001_001.Document.cstmrCdtTrfInitn accessible.
Throwable occurred: java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks)
at java.security.AccessController.throwACE(AccessController.java:100)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:174)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:544)
at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.AppletSecurity.superDotCheckPermission(AppletSecurity.java:1449)
at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.AppletSecurity.checkPermission(AppletSecurity.java:1617)
at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.AppletSecurity.checkPermission(AppletSecurity.java:1464)
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:118)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.<init>(Accessor.java:243)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.AccessorFactoryImpl.createFieldAccessor(AccessorFactoryImpl.java:67)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.createFieldSeed(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:253)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.createFieldSeed(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:82)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.findFieldProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:399)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:302)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getProperties(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:177)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:224)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:101)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:82)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:190)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:96)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:82)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:305)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:320)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:444)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:291)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1128)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:181)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:134)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:213)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:387)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:585)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:533)
at com.pradny.company.sepa.SepaExporter.generate(Unknown Source)
at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Since it runs on Notes clients, I can't just modify java.policy to give it access. Any idea how to make it work again?

Comment: Could it be related to Agent security level? Try to up it from to 2-nd or 3-th level.

Comment: I tried it already. I checked ECL and other options too. Could miss something, but I doubt it :(. I also found bug report for OpenJDK that looks similar. But I have no idea whether it could have any relevance for IBM JVM. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8035613